Mafkir Chametz in a bin over Pesach
If bin/trash collection day is during or after Pesach, is it possible to leave chametz in the bin, do the bittul, and mafkir (disown and make ownerless) it, and leave it off the property (is that necessary?)?
Would one need to also mafkir the bin itself? Or maybe sell it? How does it work, assuming it works.
